# Where to get the mod_wsgi.so file

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have to install `mod_wsgi` in Apache 2.4. I searched last two hours for the `mod_wsgi.so` file, but I can't find anything.

Where can I find this file for Apache 2.4 for Python 3.6 on Windows?

I tried to compile it myself, but I get some errors. The system cannot include ap_config.h ...

Comment: Try to download [precompiled windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi)

Comment: @RomanMindlin I have done this, but it doesn't contain the .so file. I only have a .pyd file.

Answer (score 6):

The recommended approach to installing mod_wsgi on Windows is to run:

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

Then run:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

and copy the output from that into your Apache configuration to load mod_wsgi.

Use ApacheLounge distribution and put it in `C:/Apache24`. If you don't you will need to set `MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR` environment variable when running `pip install` to tell it where your Apache installation is.

For more details see:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: Hi,
IS there any location where i can find mod-wsgi.so ,I can find other .so extension files inside modules folder but can not able to find mod-wsgi.so ,
I required mod-wsgi.so  particular file for my python 3.8 32bit .
Thank you.

Comment: @sameer_nubia - same issue - I have tried all sorts of things but it all comes back to now having a mod_wsgi.so in the modules directory!

Thankfully WAMP64 seems to be using the ApacheLounge binaries, which seem to be the only ones that mod_wsgi will definitely work with

Have tried pretty much all routes - including https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi which is one of the sources everyone quotes. Downloaded the correct 'whl' file for my setup. Still no .so file.

Close to giving up pretty much, which would be a shame.

Answer (score 0):

At least on a XAMPP/Windows installation, you don't need any mod_wsgi.so file copied to [Apache Base]/modules.

The .pyd file produced by pip: *[Python Base]\Lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi\server\mod_wsgi.cpXXX-win_amd64.pyd* works fine (tested on Win10, python 3.11, mod_wsgi 4.9.4, all amd64).

Copy the output of `C:\mod_wsgi-express module-config` to httpd.conf (e.g. C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf), and test apache server: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe` (or whatever your apache base is). If no relevant errors appear in the log file *C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log* , everything is fine, go on to configure your <VirtualHost>, web.wsgi, app.py etc.