Trouble Installing mod_wsgi.so File After pip Installation of mod-wsgi
I have tried to install the mod_wsgi.so file, but I am encountering issues with the installation of the module. Although I have already installed mod-wsgi using pip, it does not include the mod-wsgi.so file. This file is essential for me to be able to load the module in the configuration file. Without the mod-wsgi.so file, I cannot proceed with the necessary configuration to ensure proper module functionality. Therefore, I need assistance to obtain and install the mod-wsgi.so file so that I can successfully configure and load the module in the configuration file.

check the answer on this page for the installation methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402337/where-to-get-the-mod-wsgi-so-file
